# input submit click button capybara no id

Tags: button, input, click, submit, capybara

I'm trying to get a simple input submit to click using `capybara`. The submit `button` is actually on a modal. However, trying a few `capybara` still not working. Since I'm doing testing, I'm advise to not modify the code base. Adding an `id` would solve this easily but I have to do without it.

HTML code

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" value="Create" form="new_tab">
```

Capybara commands tried

```
find("input[type=submit][value='Create']").click
find('input[type]="submit"]').click
find('input[class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase"]').click
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
click_button("Create")
```

should click it, assuming it is visible on the page.
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions%3Aclick_button

Answer (score 21):

Try to use this version:

`find('input[name="commit"]').click`

It helps me all time.

Comment: saved me a lot of time